# Refactoring 2 dicts values comparision

Tags: python

I have 2 dicts and I'm comparing if values in them not the same then I add it to another dict.
But how can I make it more elegant? less code?

```
a = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Fields', 'date_of_birht': '010120'}
b = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Dwarfs', 'date_of_birht': '010121'}

for k, v in a.items():
    if b[k] != v:
        diff_in_dict_a[k] = v
        diff_in_dict_b[k] = b[k]
```

result

```
diff_in_dict_a = {'surname': 'Fields','date_of_birht': '010120'} 
diff_in_dict_b = {'surname': 'Dwarfs','date_of_birht': '010121'}
```

Comment: Your code is readable, short, idiomatic, and probably fast enough. Do not try to obfuscate it.

Comment: @Prune any sugestions for CodeReview sites?

Comment: @Prune This would be closed on Code Review for being a code snippet. There is no context, no real project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
a = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Fields', 'date_of_birht': '010120'}
b = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Dwarfs', 'date_of_birht': '010121'}

diff_in_dict_a = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if b[k] == v}
diff_in_dict_b = {k: v for k, v in b.items() if a[k] == v}
```

Comment: Lol you literally pasted the same answer I did 

Comment: When I'm writing, you posted your answer a little earier. but it's a little different of yours. I use dict.items() for extracting pair of key and value at the same time. For doing this, we can  reduce the number of accesses.

Comment: Yea don't get me wrong I like it. Great mind think a like 

Answer (score 5):

How about `set`?

```
s1 = a.items()
s2 = b.items()

dict(s1 - s2), dict(s2 - s1)
```

Output:

```
({'date_of_birht': '010120', 'surname': 'Fields'},
 {'date_of_birht': '010121', 'surname': 'Dwarfs'})
```

Comment: It does not need an explicit `set` call. `dict_items` themeselves support set operators.

Comment: @SayandipDutta I love when I learn new thing by answering ;) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would look a bit more readable, or at least a bit less code

```
x = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Fields', 'date_of_birht': '010120'}
y = {'name': 'David', 'surname': 'Dwarfs', 'date_of_birht': '010121'}

diff_a = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] != y[k]}
diff_b = {k: y[k] for k in y if k in x and y[k] != x[k]}
```